# Import MDX Code into Power Query Editor

Tags: ide, sublimetext3, powerquery

I use Sublime Text 3 as my text editor. I am also loving the new Power Query tools.

Is there a way that I can import code written in a text file into my Power Query Editor?

I would hate to go another decade being having to use an inbuilt IDE (ie VBA in Excel) when other companies are investing more in IDE UI, friendliness and plugins.

Comment: It is not MDX, it is M. I share your concerns about code development (I use Notepad++ with an M language addon) and MS are told, but they expect us to use the UI! don't know how to import into the PQ editor, copy and paste is the only thing I know of. Plugins would be great wouldn't they, let the community do what MS can't/won't/don't want to.

Comment: The Power BI team looks for top requests at the Power BI UserVoice: https://ideas.powerbi.com There's a specific thread on improving the advanced query editor: https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi/suggestions/7202913-improve-the-advanced-query-editor but if you'd rather keep your M in the file system feel free to post a new idea!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Bob. I was confused between M, MDX and DAX. Seems a different one is used between Pivot Tables, Power Query and VBA OLAP.

Comment: Personally Carl, I would want a decent IDE in Power Query rather than an import option. And the problem with that vote is that Miguel is asying MS are considering some, as soon as those some are implemented we will start a new one to ask MS to complete the job. But plugins would be great, Power Query could explode (in the best way :-)).

Comment: Mike Honey has just made a comment along the lines of what I was going to add. In Excel 2016, if that is available to you, Power Query is embedded into Excel, not an addin, and is exposed to VBA. I was playing with it, and I think you could read the text file into Excel and then write that to your datamodel in VBA. I will have a play this weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel 2016 has extended the Object Model to allow creating and changing Power Query definitions, e.g. ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add.

Here are some links for more info:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/mt574990.aspx

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/VBA-to-automate-Power-956a52d1

So you could write VBA or any other flavor of code to read M scripts from files and write them into Excel Power Query definitions.

Comment: OK that is cool. Thanks Mike. I have Excel 2016 installed but was unaware it was now available to VBA. I'll report back once I have had a play around.

Answer (score 0):

I have a small workaround for this at the moment that allows development in a separate file outside of Power Query in a text editor like Sublime and then evaluating the contents of that file using the evaluate query.

Just create a blank query, paste the below code in substituting the path for the location of your file and boom!

```
let
    Source = Text.FromBinary(File.Contents("C:\Users\KilleenJ\ProjectName\TableName.m")),
    EvaluatedExpression = Expression.Evaluate(Source, #shared)    
in
    EvaluatedExpression
```

The limitation is that you might eventually want to deploy those files with the .xlsx if you want someone else to be able to run it. You could then use the VBA script to populate the .xlsx queries once you are ready to deploy.

This wouldn't work with PowerBI because you don't have an equivalent to VBA.

I'll mark Mike's answer correct as it gets it in however both methods will work.

I prefer the evaluation method as it allows me to write in Sublime Text and then hit refresh in the Power Query editor.

I have started work on some sublime snippets over at [Github](https://github.com/jaykilleen/weetbix-sublime) that can be used until MS builds a text editor inside of Power Query that doesn't make me want to stab my eyeballs.

Ideal world would be where we can actually just import the code like we do now with a VBA module.